# How can i use IIS output cache to cache files without extension?

Tags: iis, caching, forum, outputcache

We run a busy forum, which has millions of files (forum attachments). Unfortunately, the forum software does not use a file extension for the attachments, for example

337d5a7101661519102c9c2df2712b76

We would like to use IIS output cache for our web nodes, so that we cache those static files in memory.

However, IIS requires a filename to cache a file.

Is there a workaround to this?

Thanks
Alex

Comment: If you want to use the IIS output cache, you need the file name extension when you add cachen rule. if you want to enable caching in IIS to speed performance you can try to set IIS manager->site node->HTTP Response header->Set common headers->expire web content.